# How to multiply strings in Haxe

Tags: string, haxe

I'm trying to multiply some string *a* by some integer *b* such that *a * b = a + a + a... (b times)*. I've tried doing it the same way I would in python:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a = "Text";
        var b = 4;    
        trace(a * b);    //Assumed Output: TextTextTextText
    }
}
```

But this raises:

> Build failure Test.hx:6: characters 14-15 : String should be Int

There doesn't seem to be any information in the Haxe Programming Cookbook or the API Documentation about multiplying strings, so I'm wondering if I've mistyped something or if I should use:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a = "Text";
        var b = 4;
        var c = ""; 

        for (i in 0...b) {
            c = c + a;
        }
        trace(c); // Outputs "TextTextTextText"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very short, but [array comprehension](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-array-comprehension.html) might help in some situations :

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a = "Text";
        var b = 4;
        trace( [for (i in 0...b) a].join("") );
        //Output: TextTextTextText
    }
}
```

See on [try.haxe.org](https://try.haxe.org/#68FB6).

Answer (score 4):

The numeric multiplication operator `*` requires numeric types, like integer. You have a string. If you want to multiply a string, you have to do it manually by appending a target string within the loop.

The `+` operator is not the numeric plus in your example, but a way to combine strings.

You can achieve what you want by operator [overloading](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-operator-overloading.html):

```
abstract MyAbstract(String) {
    public inline function new(s:String) {
        this = s;
    }

    @:op(A * B)
    public function repeat(rhs:Int):MyAbstract {
        var s:StringBuf = new StringBuf();
        for (i in 0...rhs)
            s.add(this);
        return new MyAbstract(s.toString());
    }
}

class Main {
    static public function main() {
        var a = new MyAbstract("foo");
        trace(a * 3); // foofoofoo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To build on [tokiop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051018/4276832), you could also define a `times` function, and then  use it as a static extension.

```
using Test.Extensions;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace ("Text".times(4));
    }
}

class Extensions {
    public static function times (str:String, n:Int) {
        return [for (i in 0...n) str].join("");
    }
}
```

[try.haxe.org demo here](https://try.haxe.org/#48688)

Answer (score 2):

To build on bsinky answer, you can also define a times function as static extension, but avoid the array:

```
using Test.Extensions;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace ("Text".times(4));
    }
}

class Extensions {
    public static function times (str:String, n:Int) {
        var v = new StringBuf();
        for (i in 0...n) v.add(str);
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

Demo: https://try.haxe.org/#e5937

> StringBuf may be optimized for different targets. For example, on JavaScript target it is compiled as if you were just using strings  https://api.haxe.org/StringBuf.html

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method (at least on the JavaScript target from https://try.haxe.org/#195A8) seems to be using `StringTools._pad`.

```
public static inline function stringProduct ( s : String, n : Int ) {

    if ( n < 0 ) {

        throw ( 1 );

    }

    return StringTools.lpad ( "", s, s.length * n );

}
```

`StringTools.lpad` and `StringTools.rpad` can't seem to decide which is more efficient. It looks like rpad might be better for larger strings and lpad might be better for smaller strings, but they switch around a bit with each rerun. `haxe.format.JsonPrinter` uses lpad for concatenation, but I'm not sure which to recommend.